# Series regex extract producing a dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am working through a regex task on Dataquest.  The following code snippet runs correctly
inside of the Dataquest IDE:

```
titles = hn["title"]
pattern = r'\[(\w+)\]'
tag_matches = titles.str.extract(pattern)
tag_freq = tag_matches.value_counts()
print(tag_freq, '\n')
```

However, on my PC running pandas 0.25.3 this exact same code block yields an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    tag_freq = tag_matches.value_counts()
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Why is tag_matches coming back as a dataframe?  I am running an extract against the series 'titles'.

Comment: Maybe try adding `, expand=False` argument to the `extract` method ...? Looks like the default value is `True` in `0.25.3`

Comment: @Chris A, that was it.  The Dataquest IDE must have that baked in somehow.

Comment: Yeh, probably using an older version of `pandas` where default was `False`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
[Pandas.Series.str.Extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

A pattern with one group will return a Series if expand=False.

```
    >>> s.str.extract(r'[ab](\d)', expand=False)
0      1
1      2
2    NaN
dtype: object
```

So perhaps you must be explicit and set expand=False to get a series object?

Comment: print(type(tag_matches))  produces:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  print(type(titles)) produces:  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>